# NextJS Link refresh page and router.push not changing page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with my setup, I have NextJS 12.2 and React 18.2.
In my Layout component I have one `<Link href="/">` and one `<button type="button" onClick={() => router.push('/login')}>`.

When I click on the link the entire page is refreshing instead of just the children layout.
When I click on the button, nothing happened.

Someone already got this type of problem with Next routing system ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].